# Problema ao tentar se conectar a um Hub SignalR+Angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, signalr

Tenho um projetinho com `WebApi`,`SignalR` e `Angularjs` onde faço algumas consultas e inserções em tempo real. Tudo funciona bem quando inicio o arquivo `index.html` direto ao rodar a aplicação, porém se tento executar o arquivo individualmente, mesmo com a aplicação rondando tenho o seguinte erro:

> hub is undefined

O erro começa nessa linha do meu controller:

```
hub.client.addItem = function(item) {
   $scope.comments.push(item);
   $scope.$apply();
}
```

E eu defino o hub no começo, dessa maneira:

```
 var hub = $.connection.myHub;
```

**Hub funcionando(Rodando direto no servidor do VS):**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Hub sem funcionar(Rodando em um servidor Python):**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi o problema referenciando o caminho do hub antes do start.

```
var hub = $.connection.myHub;
$.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:5702/signalr";
$.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
  console.log("Conectado");
}).fail(function(error) {
  console.log('Invocation of start failed. Error: ' + error)
})
```